# Is it possible to perform PCA using big csv file (1GB)?

Tags: r, csv, pca

I have a big csv file almost 1 GB, I try to perform PCA based on this file. But R report Error: cannot allocate vector of size 956.8 Mb. What should I do to solve this issue?

This 1GB file are combined by about 200 csv files. I'd like to perform PCA for this big file.

```
#Combine csv#
path <- "D:/Data process/" 
fileNames <- dir(path)  
filePath <- sapply(fileNames, function(x){ 
paste(path,x,sep='/')})   
data <- lapply(filePath, function(x){
read.csv(x, header=T, row.names=NULL)})  

#Get the big csv#

new <- dplyr::bind_rows(data)

#Perform PCA#

df <- new[,4:207]

df.pca <- prcomp(df, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 956.8 Mb
```

The expected results are to perform the PCA based on this big csv. If it is not possible, is it possible to extract information from each separated csv and then perform PCA in R? Other software is also nice for me.

Comment: Make sure you remove all variables in your environment that are not needed for prcomp() before you run prcomp().  Also, the error message you are getting may have to do with the amount of RAM you have on your computer.  Refer to page 15 of this classic book  (https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for a better explanation of the RAM issue.